# Route service doesn't work in google map when i change google.maps.LatLng

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am trying to develop a application using google map .

Description of application :

The user show see the google map on the screen and should be able to click on the map and see the point that is clicked (first click) and when the user click again the route between two location should be drawn ,

i found this :
[Working jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu9cvhLc/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Show Google Map with Latitude and Longitude in asp.net website</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function calcRoute(start, end) {

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.18061975930, 51.36565089010);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
        // marker refers to a global variable
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
            // get lat/lon of click
            var clickLat = event.latLng.lat();
            var clickLon = event.latLng.lng();

            // show in input box
            document.getElementById("lat").value = clickLat.toFixed(5);
            document.getElementById("lon").value = clickLon.toFixed(5);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(clickLat, clickLon),
                map: map
            });

            var newLatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(clickLat, clickLon);
            calcRoute(myLatlng, newLatLon);

        });
    }

    window.onload = function () { initialize() };
</script>
     <style>
 div#gmap {
        width: 80%;
        height: 500px;
        border:double;
 }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Lat: <input type="text" id='lat'>
Lon: <input type="text" id='lon'>
        <center>
            <!-- MAP HOLDER -->
            <div id="gmap"></div>
            <!-- REFERENCES -->

            lat:
            lon:

        </center>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

In the sample code i just change  this `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.18061975930, 51.36565089010);`,and when i changed it ,the routing service doesn't work .why ?
i tried that in map.google.com and it works :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you look at these link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
section "Travel Modes"

"If you request directions for a region in which that direction type is not available, the response will return the DirectionsStatus="ZERO_RESULTS"."

in your case it returns "ZERO_RESULTS":

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/refan/9rh1ddgj/2/)

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      console.log(response);
      alert(status);
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
```

Comment: When i use map.google.com ,i can get the direction between two points in my region Iran,so why here i can't ?

Comment: I tried on map.google.com, From that point 35.18061975930, 51.36565089010 it couldn't manage to draw route.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the location is too far away from any roads, so the directions service does not know where to start the route from. If you move the position closer to a road, for example like so: `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.49000000000, 51.36565089010);` then you'll see that it works.